# What is the efficient preprocessing data in image classification task with CNN?

Tags: classification, normalization, deep-learning, image-processing, data-preprocessing

I am new in deep learning on image classification. I know that Machine learning algorithm are very dependent to data normalization. Usually, if we have a training data set represented with X [N*D] where N are the number of the samples and D is the dimension. The popular preprocessing is the mean subtraction and the centering (each column (feature) will have 0 mean and 1 standard deviation). I am wondering, if we apply the same preprocessing on data set of images? What is the effect of the property of images like stationary?